# GDB Edit Assembly (Intel) Permanent and Temporary

Tags: linux, assembly, gdb, disassembly

I'm in networking and I'm absolutely new to low level programming. I've written a very simple C program to disassemble and read and crack.

What I'd like to do:
Edit the ASM of a file in GDB permanently, though I believe there is a way to do it for that run only.

`0x00000000004005f8 <+75>:   call   0x4004b0 <__isoc99_scanf@plt>`
   `0x00000000004005fd <+80>:   mov    eax,DWORD PTR [rbp-0x18]`
   `0x0000000000400600 <+83>:   cmp    eax,DWORD PTR [rbp-0x4]`

I would like to be:

`0x00000000004005f8 <+75>:   call   0x4004b0 <__isoc99_scanf@plt>`
   `0x00000000004005fd <+80>:   mov    eax,DWORD PTR [rbp-0x18]`
   `0x0000000000400600 <+83>:   cmp    eax,eax`

Thanks!

Comment: Which part do you have a problem with?  Overwriting the bytes in memory or generating the new opcode?

Comment: BTW, you can almost certainly overwrite the bytes in the file to make it permanent, too.

Comment: Probably the latter. Honestly, I know ASM better than I know GDB. I'd like to overwrite the ASM inside of it. Even if it's not permanent.

Answer (score 1):

In this case, you're in luck, since `cmp eax, eax` has a shorter encoding than `cmp eax,DWORD PTR [rbp-0x4]`.  Just replace the bytes at `0x400600` with the new instruction and a single byte `nop`.

Before:

```
Instruction                    Encoding
cmp eax,DWORD PTR [rbp-0x4]    3b 45 fc
```

After:

```
Instruction                    Encoding
cmp eax, eax                   39 c0
nop                            90
```

In GDB, you could do so by making yourself a simple pointer and then overwriting those bytes:

```
(gdb) set $p = (unsigned char *)0x400600
(gdb) set $p[0] = 0x39
(gdb) set $p[1] = 0xc0
(gdb) set $p[2] = 0x90
```